# Splitting a file by line count using AWK while appending a separate header

Tags: csv, awk, header-files

Say I have a file of 101 lines called file100.csv, with the first row being the header. I want to be able to split that file into 10 files of 1+10 lines named N.file100.csv, where N = 1-10, and that the header being added to all 10 files as the first line

So far, I can isolate the header and split the files no problem:

```
head -n 1 file100.csv > tmpHeader
tail -n +2 file100.csv | awk '{filename = int((NR-1)/10)+1 ".file100.csv"; print >> filename}' -
```

What I'm having trouble with is attaching that header file as the first row to all subsequent 10 files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk 'NR==1 {a=$0; next} (NR-2)%10==0 {filename = int((NR-2)/10)+1 ".file100.csv"; print a >> filename} {print >> filename}' file100.csv
```

**Explanation:**

- `NR==1 {a=$0; next}` reads the first line of the file and stores the header in the variable `a`.
- `(NR-2)%10==0 {filename = int((NR-2)/10)+1 ".file100.csv"; print a >> filename}` generates the filename, it's the same as in your command. We only have to write the header when the filename changes. This is every 10th line, considering the offset coming with the header.
- `{print >> filename}` prints every line to the current file.

Answer (score 0):

1. AWK can match not only by regexp but by any boolean. Match current line number NR to find first line line and rest of the lines. **NR == 1 { head = $0 }**.
2. When every x-th line, generate new file name and print header separately into the file. Every 5-th in my case: **NR % 5 == 2 { filename =int((NR-1)/5)+1; print head > filename }**
3. Print rest of the lines into current file name: **NR != 1 { print >> filename }**

   cat file100.csv | awk 'NR == 1 { head = $0 } NR % 5 == 2 { filename = int((NR-1)/5)+1 ".file100.csv"; print head > filename } NR != 1 { print >> filename }'